# Word Macro - replace a fixed text with a variable that increase by a certain step

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word VBA that I want to make it a bit smarter.  Right now, it serves me well but I still have to do a manual step, which I would like to eliminate.  The macro replaces a string found in a selection.  This string is "XXXX" which is found more than once.  I prompt the user to enter a value for the variable that will replace the "XXXX".  However, all the occurrences will be replaced by the same variable.  I would like to be able to increase each instance by an increment of 2.  So, if the user enters 402, I want the macro to find the first occurrence in the selection and replace it with 402, but the next occurrence should be replaced with 404, next 406, etc...

I tried to increment the "i" by two in the macro, but the macro goes ahead and replaces all the "XXXX" with the input variable.  Any help or guidance would be very appreciated.

Here's my macro so far that needs to be enhanced.

```
Sub my_convert_to_PROCESS_steps_addBLOCKs()
'
' my_convert_to_PROCESS_steps Macro
'
'
    
Dim aRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim intRowCount As Integer
Dim MyInput As Variant

intRowCount = 1

'Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range

'Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    
With Selection.Find
Do
    .Text = "XXXX " ' the word I am looking for
    .Execute
        If .Found Then
        MyInput = InputBox(" ", "Process Block Sequence", "Enter Block Starting Number (e.g., 402)")
           
           i = MyInput
            .Replacement.Text = "At block " & i & ", the device may "
            
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
         
            i = i + 2

        End If
                Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Loop While .Found

        End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my own question. I had already worked on a similar one before.  Here's the new code:

```
Sub my_convert_to_PROCESS_steps_addBLOCKs_new()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
Dim MyInput As Variant

With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "XXXX"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
         MyInput = InputBox(" ", "Process Block Sequence", "Enter Block Starting Number (e.g., 402)")
           
        i = MyInput
        
        Do While .Find.Found
       
    .Text = "At block " & i & ", the device may"
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
    i = i + 2
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```